# here im getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <.why is it so

Tags: javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
        client_id: 'PWWWDURZZ33QK15R5YA3POXMQS0E22CX4QUX2OXAQVYQYN44',
        response_type: 'code',
        redirect_uri: "http://192.168.10.12:9000/mobile",
        jsonp: 'parseResponse'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: where are you getting that error?In the success function?Help us help you byputting some effort in the question

Comment: I hope you are definitely including jquery library in your html/jsp. Let us know in which line ur getting this exception..check in firebug..

Answer (score 1):

That's because the resource that you request returns an HTML document instead of a JSONP response.